# Access C++ map with dot syntax

Tags: c++

Is it possible to make a map class whose values are accessible with a dot-like notation?

I'd like to do something like this:

```
class Constants: std::map<std::string, float> {
    Constant(std:string filename) {
         /* Loads a key-value configuration file */
    }
    // Some magic here that lets me access
    // the underlying map with Constants.alpha
    // in addition to Constants["alpha"]
}

Constants C137("Dimesnion_C-137.txt");
Constants C131("Dimension_C-131.txt");
cout << C137["alpha"] << endl; // I can already do this
cout << C137.alpha << endl;    // I'd like to do this
```

The code should behave literally as if whatever is written after the dot was into the string argument of the []-notation, that is `C137.foo` should behave exactly as if it was written `C137["foo"]`, whether or not the underlying map contains the key.

The configuration file is comprised of a list of constants stored as key-value. Constants names are alphanumeric only, no spaces or special characters, and never begin with a number.

```
G        6.67430E-11
hbar     1.054571817E-34
alpha    7.2973525628E-3
...
```

I have many files, some of the constants are shared, but some are not (and many are in a single file only). Therefore I'd rule out the possibility of adding each constant as a class-member, because I simply would have too many of them. I decided to load them into a `std::map<std::string, float>` instead. If there was no way to do what I would like to do I would still use a `std::map` to hold the constants, and access them the usual way with the operator [].

The purpose of this is to avoid flooding my code with square brackets and strings:

```
Constants consts('constants.txt');
/* Write this */
mu_B = 0.5*const.electroncharge*const.hbar/const.electronmass;
/* Instead of this */
mu_B = 0.5*const["electroncharge"]*const["hbar"]/const["electronmass"];
```

I can achieve a similar result in Python:

```py
class Constants(dict):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        # Load the file ...
        pass
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self[attr]

consts = Constants('constants.txt')
print(consts.alpha)  # Equivalent to consts["alpha"]
```

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: You can't overload `operator.`, if that's what you're asking.  I suspect the view was taken that it would be too confusing.  You can, however, overload `operator->`, so perhaps there's some mileage in that.

Comment: [`operator.()`](https://isocpp.org/blog/2016/02/a-bit-of-background-for-the-operator-dot-proposal-bjarne-stroustrup) has only come as far as to being a proposal.

Comment: Q: Have you considered simply loading your config into a struct (instead of using a map)?  To give you `config.electroncharge`, etc...

Comment: @TedLyngmo I've run out of comment upvotes :(

Comment: @PaulSanders :-) here, have one of mine

Comment: @TedLyngmo Brilliant (the mods will pull all this!)

Comment: I'd really parse that into some kind of strongly typed structure. Using dynamic keys for configuration values is incredibly error prone. Even _if_ C++ let you hide that behind syntactic sugar, it still wouldn't fix the underlying problem.

Comment: @PaulSanders `C137->("alpha")` would be even more to type than `C137["alpha"]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't overload `operator .` so there is no way to do that to a map.

But is a map really the right structure anyway? From the examples it looks to me like you are defining some scientific constants and units. Not random user supplied config options. So all entries would be known at compile time and not change.

Sounds to me like a use case for https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal

If you define a bunch of user defined literals then

```
mu_B = 0.5*const["electroncharge"]*const["hbar"]/const["electronmass"];
```

becomes for example

```
mu_B = 0.5_ec * 1_hbar / 1_electronmass;
```